# Java 9 module cannot access files in same module

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, java-module

The whole project can be viewed [here](https://github.com/findusl/SE73000124).

I have the following minimal demo project:

```
package com.example.demo

import io.swagger.annotations.Api

@Api(tags = [API_NAME])
class DemoClass

const val API_NAME = "demo"

fun main() = println("Hello World!")
```

Works perfectly fine as is. However now I want to add the Java 9 module system. I add a `module-info.java` under src/main/kotlin with this content:

```
module com.example.demo {
    requires swagger.annotations;
    requires kotlin.stdlib;
}
```

This leads to the following compiler error (you can find the complete mvn output at the end of the question):

> E:\demo\src\main\kotlin\com\example\demo\DemoClass.kt:[5,18] Symbol is declared in module 'com.example.demo' which does not export package 'com.example.demo'

The problem is with the API_NAME constant used in the @Api annotation. It works if I export the `com.example.demo` package in the `module-info.java`, but I don't want to do that. What else can I do?

I use Maven as a build system and the pom.xml is standard. It is a bit big, mostly due to the kotlin plugin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.7.10</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the complete output of `mvn clean install -e`:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------< com.example:demo >--------------------------
[INFO] Building demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ demo ---
[INFO] Deleting E:\demo\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Required filename-based automodules detected: [swagger-annotations-1.6.6.jar]. Please don't publish this project to a public artifact repository!
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to E:\demo\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- kotlin-maven-plugin:1.7.10:compile (compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] Applied plugin: 'spring'
[ERROR] E:\demo\src\main\kotlin\com\example\demo\DemoClass.kt: (5, 18) Symbol is declared in module 'com.example.demo' which does not export package 'com.example.demo'
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.825 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-16T01:49:05+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.7.10:compile (compile) on project demo: Compilation failure
[ERROR] E:\demo\src\main\kotlin\com\example\demo\DemoClass.kt:[5,18] Symbol is declared in module 'com.example.demo' which does not export package 'com.example.demo'
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.7.10:compile (compile) on project demo: Compilation failure
E:\demo\src\main\kotlin\com\example\demo\DemoClass.kt:[5,18] Symbol is declared in module 'com.example.demo' which does not export package 'com.example.demo'

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
E:\demo\src\main\kotlin\com\example\demo\DemoClass.kt:[5,18] Symbol is declared in module 'com.example.demo' which does not export package 'com.example.demo'

    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.MavenPluginLogMessageCollector.throwKotlinCompilerException (MavenPluginLogMessageCollector.java:111)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompileMojoBase.execute (KotlinCompileMojoBase.java:212)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.K2JVMCompileMojo.execute (K2JVMCompileMojo.java:222)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Mind adding the full stacktrace? (A module always reads itself, and all its packages are implicitly exported to itself - so it seems an other module tries to access it. But which one?)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I added the -e flag to the maven command and copied the output to the question. I hope that is the information you are looking for?

Comment: Ok, happens during compilation. I believe this is a bug in the kotlin compiler - as a module does export all its packages to itself.